# How to find where a custom Vue component is defined?

Tags: vue.js, components

I'm working on an unfamiliar codebase which includes some components, `<v-content>`, `<v-card>` etc.

Is there a reliable way to determine where they are defined? (Obviously I can google this particular example - I'm looking for a general technique for mapping a component name back to its definition.)

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming you're referring to global components, as local component registration requires explicitly importing the component from a particular source directory or module, in which case the source of the component would be obvious.

[Global component registration](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-registration.html#Global-Registration) syntax is:

```js
Vue.component('componentName', ...)
```

Therefore, you could search your source directory (including `node_modules`) for that sequence. For example, you could `grep` it with:

```
grep -nr Vue\\.component .
```

Comment: I wasn't necessarily limiting to just global components, but your comment re: local components makes sense.

Comment: In this case, it seems that the library is Vuetify, which indirectly imports all the subcomponents. It's loaded with `Vue.use(Vuetify)` not `Vue.component()`...

Comment: That's the entry into the plug-in, which internally [uses `Vue.component`](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/blob/c7cbdc5/packages/vuetify/src/install.ts#L27). Allow me to expand my answer to include local components, Vuetify, and potential search caveats.